# using panda dataframe, how to calculate average of sequence of data in csv log file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to take the average of sequence of repeating rows. For example,

```
a   0.1
b   0.2
c   0.2
a   0.4
b   0.1
c   0.3
a   0.4
b   0.5
c   0.3
```

and I want the following output.

```
a   0.300
b   0.267
c   0.267
```

I was able to read csv file as dataframe and sort by column index but I would like to maintain the sequence..

Thank you

Comment: `df.groupby('col0')['col1'].mean()`?

Comment: thanks. for 'col0', I get KeyError: 'col0'

But this works. thank you so much.

df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[1]].mean()

Comment: I have more than two columns. But group by removes other columns. How do I get other column to df2?

Comment: @RedFox my answer deals with the issue of getting the other columns all together. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing @Quang Hoang and your commentary, you could either deal with other columns applying some kind of aggregation too, like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"],
                   'col1':[0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3],
                   'col2':[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'col3':["x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z"]})

df2 = df.groupby('col0')[['col1','col2']].mean()

print(df2)
```

That gives you:

```
          col1      col2
col0                    
a     0.300000  1.666667
b     0.266667  1.333333
c     0.266667  1.666667
```

And/or you could merge the desired data with the new data frame. As something like this:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df, on='col0', how='left')
```

Giving you this:

```
   col0    col1_x    col2_x  col1_y  col2_y col3
0    a  0.300000  1.666667     0.1       2    x
1    a  0.300000  1.666667     0.4       1    x
2    a  0.300000  1.666667     0.4       2    x
3    b  0.266667  1.333333     0.2       1    y
4    b  0.266667  1.333333     0.1       2    y
5    b  0.266667  1.333333     0.5       1    y
6    c  0.266667  1.666667     0.2       2    z
7    c  0.266667  1.666667     0.3       1    z
8    c  0.266667  1.666667     0.3       2    z
```

But obviously it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's nothing! I'm glad to help :)